# Incorrect server-side validate Apple's in app purchase (IAP)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I try to validate ios's in app purchase using server-side, as decribe here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

But I found some user can by-pass this validation. They buy a productId many times (in the fact that this productId is supposed to buy only 1 time), but Apple server said that all receipts are valid (status = 0). It make my revenue report is incorrect.

How could I actually verify a Apple's IAP receipt in more trustable way?

Comment: If it is a non-consumable IAP are they simply restoring that purchase on another device?  What is in the `original_transaction_id` field of the receipt?  How would by-passing receipt validation be related to purchasing multiple times?

Comment: Oh, I found that each time user use a different receipt, but the original_transaction_id is remain same.

Comment: And in more details,  "receipt_creation_date": "2019-09-05 02:01:19 Etc/GMT" but "original_purchase_date": "2019-03-08 07:22:23 Etc/GMT". Does it mean user refund purchase?

Comment: No, they may have purchased the same item again (Apple processes the purchase at $0) or they may have restored the purchase on another device (or the same device after deleting & reinstalling your app)

Comment: Yes I know, but our system use a seperate log event system to estimate revenue, then each purchase generate a new log event. And in that case, we cannot detect if this receipt is refund or not.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by refund. If Apple cancels the transaction then there will be a cancellation date in the receipt.

Comment: I mean each time user purchase, i receive a new receipt, and my system count it as a valid revenue. But in my case, many receipts has same original_transaction_id (as you mentioned above), then it cause misleading to my system (revenue is much more than actual). Should I store original_transaction_id and count revenue only 1 time for each original_transaction_id?

Comment: Yes, that would seem like the right approach.

Comment: Thank you, and one more thing, after validate I receive an array of "in_app" (history purchase of user, I guess), how do I know which is current transaction? Is it the first element of array?

Comment: Check the purchase data field ?

Comment: Thank you very much, receipt verify doesn't contains current transaction id by itself, but I got it from IAP response, beside receipt.